# Flask CGI deploy on cPanel gives error 500

Tags: python, apache, flask, cgi, cpanel

Stucked on little thing. I'm getting error 500, when running Flask app on cPanel.

```
[begaeuor@miami ~]$ python -V
Python 2.7.5
[begaeuor@miami ~]$
```

When I open python, I can import Flask package (Flask is installed system-wide).
Also I got installed, VirtualEnv, with Flask, but still no success.

```
[begaeuor@miami ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
[begaeuor@miami ~]$
```

Now. I get into cgi-bin, and created .cgi file:

```
#!/home/begaeuor/flaskdeploy/virtualenv-12.0.7/venv/bin/

from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler

from app import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

and also .py file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')

def home():

    return "Hello!"



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Chmod is `0755` on both files.
Line endings is `Unix` (Sublime Text 3)

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your webservers error log for details about the problem.

Comment: Apache logs empty, error_log empty.